# Bubble sort adaptive (java)

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm writing up the Bubble Sort algorithm with worst case runtime of O(n^2) and best case of O(n) so that it is adaptive. My idea was to add some sort of boolean flag variable to control the while loop so that the algorithm would stop early if it was sorted early. However, it keeps failing my JUnit testing. I think it's the way I'm implementing the boolean variable but I'm not sure where else to put it. Any contributions would be greatly appreciated.

```
    public static<T> void bubbleSort(T[] arr, Comparator<T> comparator) {
        if (arr == null || comparator == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Comparator nor array can be null.");
        }
        boolean swapped = true;

        while (swapped) {
            swapped = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < arr.length - i - 1, j++) {
                    if (comparator.compare(arr[j], arr[j + 1]) > 0) {
                        T obj = arr[j];
                        arr[j] = arr[j + 1]
                        arr[j + 1] = obj;
                        swapped = true;
                    }
                }
           }
       }
  }
```

EDIT: here are the JUNITS I am using.

```
public class SortingTests {
    private TeachingAssistant[] tas;
    private TeachingAssistant[] tasByName;
    private ComparatorPlus<TeachingAssistant> comp;
    private static final int TIMEOUT = 200;

@Before
public void setUp() {
        tas = new TeachingAssistant[10];
        tas[0] = new TeachingAssistant("Adrianna");
        tas[1] = new TeachingAssistant("Chad");
        tas[2] = new TeachingAssistant("Jackie");
        tas[3] = new TeachingAssistant("Miguel");
        tas[4] = new TeachingAssistant("Ashley");
        tas[5] = new TeachingAssistant("Scott");
        tas[6] = new TeachingAssistant("Tim");
        tas[7] = new TeachingAssistant("Joey");
        tas[8] = new TeachingAssistant("Raymond");
        tas[9] = new TeachingAssistant("Bartosz");
        tasByName = new TeachingAssistant[10];
        tasByName[0] = tas[0];
        tasByName[1] = tas[4];
        tasByName[2] = tas[9];
        tasByName[3] = tas[1];
        tasByName[4] = tas[2];
        tasByName[5] = tas[7];
        tasByName[6] = tas[3];
        tasByName[7] = tas[8];
        tasByName[8] = tas[5];
        tasByName[9] = tas[6];

        comp = TeachingAssistant.getNameComparator();
    }

    @Test(timeout = TIMEOUT)
    public void testBubbleSort() {
        Sorting.bubbleSort(tas, comp);
        assertArrayEquals(tasByName, tas);
        assertTrue("Number of comparisons: " + comp.getCount(),
                comp.getCount() <= 44 && comp.getCount() != 0);
}
```

Comment: Where is the failing test?

Comment: I suggest taking out `swapped` and all the code that sets or tests it, and getting the underlying sort working correctly first.  That should also help you recognize how and where an early termination condition such as you are trying to implement should be applied.

Comment: your swapped varibale makes not that much sense for me, because if you set the  variable to false after the for with the 'i' then you should not Need the `swapped = true` any more if you set it to true before the while like you did.

Comment: In the current implementation it won't work as intended: You have one loop too many. The two `for` loops will currently guarantee O(n2) steps. Instead remove the inner loop and use `i` instead of `j`.

Comment: Have you noticed that the block of the test `if (arr == null || comparator == null) {` is not closed.

Comment: Just did thank you, Maurice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
public static<T> void bubbleSort(T[] arr, Comparator<T> comparator) {

    if (arr == null || comparator == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Comparator nor array can be null.");
    boolean swapped = true;

    while (swapped) {
        swapped = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            if (comparator.compare(arr[i], arr[i + 1]) > 0) {
                T obj = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1]
                arr[i + 1] = obj;
                swapped = true;
            }
       }
   }


 }
```

Comment: Could you add a sentence or two about the changes you made and why it didn't work before?

Comment: In this code if swap is done then the next loop will run till the end of the array and not to (arr.len-i). It is still O(n^2) both cases but you can save does extra steps... see my answer using 2 for loop with break

Comment: This answer is flawed. Although it works, and will halt when the array is sorted, it always works on the entire array. It doesn't take advantage of the higher elements "bubbling" to the end. It will *always* be slower than the version that uses two loops and a `break`. One could make the argument that this isn't even really a Bubblesort, since it doesn't take advantage of the "bubbling" behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want to achieve O(n) in case the array is already sorted (or half sorted). If you want to improve your time complexity you need to do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
     boolean swapped = false;
     for (int j = 0; j < arr.length - i - 1, j++) {
          if (comparator.compare(arr[j], arr[j + 1]) > 0) {
              T obj = arr[i];
              arr[i] = arr[i + 1]
              arr[i + 1] = obj;
              swapped = True;
          }
     }
     if (swapped == false)
         break; // no inner swap done so can exit the upper loop
}
```